# NextJS Image component incorrect path

Tags: reactjs, image, next.js, nextjs-image

I'm working on a NextJS application and I'm having trouble getting the Image component to work.

The normal img element works fine using the same src attribute path as the Image component.

My project has the standard public folder and inside it I have an image called nageldog.png

```
import Image from "next/image";
...
<img src="/nageldog.png" alt="a"/>
<Image src="/nageldog.png" alt="b" width="64" height="64" />
...
```

### In the browser console

---

the src path generated for the `<img>` element looks fine:

`<img src="/nageldog.png" alt="a">`

---

the src path generated for the `<Image>` component looks odd:

`<img alt="b" src="/_next/image?url=%2Fnageldog.png&amp;w=256&amp;q=75"`

---

I receive an error in console: "Failed to load resource... status 500" for `http://localhost:3000/_next/image?url=%2Fnageldog.png&w=64&q=75`

Why won't the Image component load? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you have a typo or an extra space somewhere? If it is directly in the public folder, than this should work.

Comment: I did the exact same thing with a new `create-next-app` app, with a file having the same name, and didn't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, any solution you did?

Answer (score 0):

use loader attribute.

`<Image src={iconSrc} loader={() => item.iconSrc} alt="Picture of the author" />`

Answer (score 0):

an update for newbies in nextjs like me.
static files are served in public folder in the root directory:
[nextjs doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/static-assets)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you can import static images like this

```
import Image from 'next/image'
import mypic from '../nageldog.png'

const MyImage = (props) => {
  return (
    <Image src={mypic} alt="Picture of the author" />
  )
```

the problem i have with is when having a lot of images in the public folder